# video streaming from python tto android application

Tags: python, android, video-streaming

I tried video streaming using python flask using [this repo](https://github.com/miguelgrinberg/flask-video-streaming/) - but the video lags during streaming over Wi-Fi. Can you please suggest a proper and smooth video streaming option over the Wi-Fi using Python to android application

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Which filename in repo link?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.